# Flow Conditional Visibility for Radio Buttons

Tags: visual-workflow

Any flow experts out there? I am trying to use the [new component visibility feature in flow](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_conditionals.htm) that was released in Winter 20.

I have a screen input radio button element for my choices.  Depending on which one the user selects, I would like a second component to show up.  Using the below visibility filter on the 2nd component, I have been able to get the 2nd component to "not" show up at the start screen (yay!).

However, when the user selects the correct radio button in the 1st component/start screen, the 2nd component doesn't show up like it should. How should this filter actually look? I think it may have something to do with globalconstant.true.

Set Component Visibility:

> All Conditions Are Met (AND) {!RadioButton1}
>   Equals{!$GlobalConstant.True}

Thanks!
Ann

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Might be a bit of dumb question, but are you referencing the right radio button?

Comment: I believe so.  My first component is a radio button with choices.  {!RadioButton1} is one of the choices. My second component references that radio button with the equals true after it. When i have that conditional visibility active, the 2nd component does not show up.  It does not come back regardless of which radio button is selected.

Comment: Can you post what your radio button configuration looks like? I'm curious if the radio buttons referencing a Choice resource, in which case you would want to check if the radio button value equals the choice resource, not the global constant.

Comment: Ok.  I rebuilt my screens a little for privacy, but still experienced the same incorrect result.  I added 3 images to the post.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: That's OK - I think I see the problem. Writing you an answer momentarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition for visibility is checking whether RadioButton1 equals $GlobalConstant.True. But if you want the Stores Issues radio group to be displayed based on what's selected in the Call Category radio group, what you need to check is what the value of the *radio button group* is. In your example, RadioButton1 is a Choice resource, not a radio group.

If you want to display the Stores Issues radio group when the first radio button (RadioButton1) in the Call Category is selected, your criteria would be:

> All Conditions are Met (AND) **{!Call_Category_0} Equals {!RadioButton1}**

Your second group wasn't showing up in the start screen because the RadioButton1 Choice is of type Text, and you're comparing it to the boolean true. Assuming RadioButton1 has a text value, that comparison will always be false.

Comment: That's awesome.  And makes perfect sense now that you explain it! I just tested and it works great.  Thanks so much!

Comment: That's great! Please take  moment to mark the answer as correct, so when other people run into the same problem, they know it's the right solution. And welcome to Salesforce StackExchange!

Comment: But how do i do that if i use a choice set from records as my radio buttons options?